# How to restore a session in a Servlet created in another on Glassfishv4?

Tags: java, servlets, glassfish

LogonServlet gets user data and saves them as session variable (or an object that needs these data for creation) that all other servlets can restore and use it. These other servlets get called independently by the same app.

Do I need to forward something to them? I can't forward the request I send to one servlet to another because I send different datatypes to different servlets. I have no idea what I am doing wrong or how I could do it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't know that I have to manage the session cookies in my Application that communicates with the servlets manually and add them to every http request to inform the server that I am user X which also initiated the session.

So it is necessary to save the cookies I receive from the first HTTP response and add them to all follow up HTTP requests that should happen during the same session.

When you just want your application to communicate with your own webservice via HTTP you can set the cookie store to accept all cookies.